# Como inserir valores de um JSON no PostgreSQL utilizando NodeJS?

Tags: json, node.js, postgresql, post

Pretendo realizar um insert em uma tabela no PostgreSQL.

Os valores que serão utilizados na query são de um JSON no qual tenho acesso por um GET.

```
fetch(
"https://api.fitbit.com/1/user/-/activities/steps/date/2021-03-23/today.json",
{
method: "GET",
headers: { Authorization: "Bearer " + access_token },
}
).then((value) => value.json())
 .then((json) => {
  console.log(json);
```

O arquivo JSON do código acima:

```
'activities-steps': [
{ dateTime: '2021-03-23', value: '3463' },
{ dateTime: '2021-03-24', value: '449' }, 
{ dateTime: '2021-03-25', value: '4794' },
{ dateTime: '2021-03-26', value: '4992' },
{ dateTime: '2021-03-27', value: '489' }, 
{ dateTime: '2021-03-28', value: '781' }, 
{ dateTime: '2021-03-29', value: '706' }
```

A conexão com o banco funciona perfeitamente e já possuo a function para o insert:

```
async function insertSetps(stepstable) {
const client = await connect();
const sql = "INSERT INTO steps (date,value) VALUES ($1,$2);";
const values = [stepstable.date, stepstable.value];
return await client.query(sql, values);
}
module.exports = { insertSetps };
```

Como passo os valores do JSON acima dentro da função insertSetps abaixo?

```
(async () => {
  const db = require("./db.js");

  console.log("Início do insert");
  const result = await db.insertSetps({date: VALORES, value: VALORES});
  console.log(result.rowCount);
})();
```

Alguém poderia me ajudar? Obrigado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Poderia fazer as inserções utilizando um comando de repetição, e iterar os elementos contidos no array `activities-steps`.

Uma maneira de resolver é iterando sobre os itens utilizando `for..of` e fazer a inserção com auxilio do comando `await`

```
async function insertSetps(stepstable) {
    const client = await connect();
    const sql = "INSERT INTO steps (date,value) VALUES ($1,$2)";
    for (const linha of atividades['activities-steps']) {
        const values = [linha.dateTime, linha.value]
        try {
            await client.query(sql,values)
        } catch (e) {
            console.log('Houve um erro: '+e)
        }
    
    }
    console.log({'msg': 'ok'})
}
module.exports = { insertSetps };
```

Não ficou claro em qual momento é lido o json, então vou colocar como um comentário a leitura do json, e como seria a chamada da função para fazer a inserção:

```
( async () => {
  const db = require("./db.js");
  //ler json
  //estou supondo que fez a leitura da api fitbit e colocou o conteúdo na variável json conforme o seu exemplo
  const json = {'activities-steps': [
    { dateTime: '2021-03-23', value: '3463' },
    { dateTime: '2021-03-24', value: '449' }, 
    { dateTime: '2021-03-25', value: '4794' },
    { dateTime: '2021-03-26', value: '4992' },
    { dateTime: '2021-03-27', value: '489' }, 
    { dateTime: '2021-03-28', value: '781' }, 
    { dateTime: '2021-03-29', value: '706' }]
  }
  await db.insertSetps(json);
  console.log('Dados inseridos');
})();
```

Comment: obrigado! A solução foi neste caminho. Fiz um for para percorrer toda string do JSON e consegui pegar cada valor e inserir na query.